# Given 2 LINESTRINGS in PostGIS that touch, how to join them together?

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a table in PostGIS & PostgreSQL with a LINESTRING column. I am constructing a query that's the result of joining this table with itself, and I know that the geometry columns (call them `geom`) of each one connect, i.e. the first row is a LINESTRING from `A--B--…---K` and the second row is `K--L--…--T`, i.e. the last point of the first LINESTRING is the same as the first point of the second LINESTRING.

Is there some function/expression where "concatinate"/"join"/"merge"/"extend" these 2 LINESTRINGs into 1 LINESTRING that looks like `A--B--…--K--L--…--T`?

Comment: ST_MakeLine(linestringA, linestringB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [ST_Union](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-svn/ST_Union.html) in a query like this:

```
SELECT ST_Union(the_geom) from mytable;
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at :

http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Union.html

It would return the union of the two geometries which should be a single linestring.